# Why CPU and GPU load so low in the process of opencv_traincascade?

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I build the project with CUDA module. Well, I think I did something incorrect because GPU load in process of train(8000 pos and 3000 neg) is 6%(Nvidia QUADRO). And CPU: On precalculation stage CPU load is 100%(core i7), but then falling down on 12%, and keep working on it. Can you give me some advise, what I should do? I'm new in OpenCV and want to learn it.

**EDIT**
There is no code writing by me. It is a module .exe of OpenCV library.

Comment: Some code would be nice, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV doesn't have implicit CUDA optimization. `opencv_gpu` is a separate module and users should explicitly use it to enable CUDA optimization. `opencv_traincascade` doesn't use `gpu` module, so it doesn't work on GPU.

You can find more information in reference manual: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.6/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html

and in gpu samples: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/gpu

Comment: Thank you. I thought that there is CUDA, because of chart on this page of documentation: http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html